# Algorithm to reduce decimals in the pattern of 0.2 -> 0.1 -> 0.09 -> 0.08 -> ... -> 0.02 -> 0.01 -> 0.009

Tags: python, algorithm, decimal

I am attempting to automate the decaying of a neural network's learning rate. I would like to write a function that is called if the neural net's loss does not reduce over *n* epochs.

This function will take the current learning rate as a parameter and then will reduce it by 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc, depending on it's current value (the number of significant figures it currently has). This would give the decaying pattern of 0.2 -> 0.1 -> 0.09 -> 0.08 -> ... -> 0.02 -> 0.01 -> 0.009

As a guideline, I currently have the learning rate decaying as below, starting at 0.1:

```
def decayLearningRate(learningRate):
    return learningRate ** 2
```

However, these jumps are too big. What is an elegant way to achieve what I have proposed?

Note: The learning rate will always begin at 0.1 or less.

Comment: What is the logic behind the pattern you want? if it's a math function just write it down the code!

Comment: `r = r-r/float(str(r)[-1]) if r-r/float(str(r)[-1]) !=0 else float('.' + ''.join(['0' for x in range(len(str(r))-2)]) + '9')`

Comment: alternatively: `r = r-r/float(str(r)[-1]) if r-r/float(str(r)[-1]) !=0 else 9*10**-(len(str(r))-1)`

Comment: Are you sure you really want an answer to this? ;-)  Sometimes you're cutting the rate in half, other times just reducing it by 10%.  What's the problem with, e.g., the very simple `return learningRate * 0.9` (always reduce it by 10%)?

Comment: @MohammadAthar How is your code going to go from `0.000001` to `0.0000009` when `str(r)[-1]` is going to be `6`? Are you going to expand it even further to write a hacky parser for exponential notation too?

Comment: If you want to use an exponential function, but `** 2` is too fast, use `** 1.4`, or some other value that you like better. Or, if you specifically want to hit the values `0.2` then `0.02` ten steps later then `0.002` ten steps later, find the curve that fits those values and use that curve's equation. Unless you actually _want_ it to be jagged and inconsistent for some reason?

Comment: The closed-form equation for your values, rounded to a couple digits, is `0.2 * exp(-.23 * stepnumber)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm calling `x-y problem` on this question.  Look on line for typical learning-rate decay patterns; what you're doing isn't smooth.  In each sequence of 10*N epochs (where `N` is your impatience interval), you start with a 10% decay, then accelerate the decay to 11%, 12.5%, ... 50%, at which point you reset to 10%.

Rather, just pick a proportion that works for your application.  Classically, various applications have used anything from 10% to a factor 3 (or even 10):

```
return learning_rate * 0.90
return learning_rate / 3
return learning_rate /10
```

As will all unspecified applications, you'll have to experiment with your `N` and the factor you use, to see what works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure that it's *the* elegant solution, but it's a way to achieve a task:

```
from decimal import Decimal

value = Decimal('0.3')
n = 15

for i in range(n):
    last_digit = value.as_tuple().digits[-1]

    if last_digit == 1:
        value -= value / 10
    else:
        value -= value / last_digit
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
0.2
0.1
0.09
0.08
0.07
0.06
0.05
0.04
0.03
0.02
0.01
0.009
0.008
0.007
0.006
```